# Hibernate throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.log.ConnectionPoolingLogger

Tags: hibernate, version, connection-pooling, hibernate-mapping, c3p0

After upgrading Hibernate from 5.0.0 to 5.4.4 version, getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.log.ConnectionPoolingLogger` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include core lib jar in your local project. Download [hibernate-core-5.4.4.Final.jar](https://app.box.com/s/xvy7jzsmb9nmvpplqv1p38v2zn3dl6o0) or [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core)